# How to add children in firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to add child after child to achieve the form i want, and i dont want to use push or uid.

The form i want is:

Orders: - phonenumber: -order1 :-{data1}

Here is my code

```
val firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
              firebaseDatabase.child("Orders").child("Key").setValue("+12345")
              firebaseDatabase.child("Orders").child("+12345").child("Key").setValue("order1")
              firebaseDatabase.child("Orders").child("+12345").child("order1").setValue(data1)
```

I tried searching everywhere on this forum but couldnt find a reliable answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want this form:

```
Orders: 
   - phonenumber: 
         -order1 :
             -{data1}
```

Then do the following:

```
val firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
firebaseDatabase.child("Orders").child("+1234").child("order1").setValue(data1)
```

This will give you:

```
Orders
   +1234
      order1 : data1
```

If `data1` is `keys` and `values`, then do the following:

```
val firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
val ref = firebaseDatabase.child("Orders").child("+1234").child("order1")
ref.child("name").setValue("john")
ref.child("age").setValue(123)
```

This will give you the following:

```
Orders
   +1234
      order1
         name : john
         age : 123
```

Comment: Ah my problem was that i didnt have my firebase write rule set to true, how can i change it to false and allow him to access it according to his phone number and not his uid?